# GLib:C: How do I print a GValue

Tags: c, gtk, glib

How do I `g_print` a `GValue`, if I don't know it's type at compile time?

Is there some kind of special format character for the `g_print` format string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what format you want to print it in. If you don’t really care about the format, you can use `g_value_transform()` to convert the value into a second `GValue` which has been initialised with type `G_TYPE_STRING`.

If you do care about the format, you will need to have a multi-branch `if` statement which compares the value of `G_VALUE_TYPE()` for your `GValue` against many different `GType`s. In the body of each `if` block you’d have type-specific printing code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`g_strdup_value_contents`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Generic-values.html#g-strdup-value-contents):

```
gchar * strVal = g_strdup_value_contents (&gvalue);
g_print ("gvalue: %s\n", strVal);
free (strVal);
```